# Error while compiling release build in Android Studio 3.0 RC2

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle

How can I fix this issues while compiling release build in Android Studio 3.0 RC2

> Error:Error: commons-logging defines classes that conflict with
>   classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer
>   versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem
>   (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead),
>   or repackaging the library using something like jarjar.
>   [DuplicatePlatformClasses]
>
> Error:Error: httpclient defines classes that conflict with classes now
>   provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or
>   alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example,
>   for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or
>   repackaging the library using something like jarjar.
>   [DuplicatePlatformClasses]

My build.gradle is

```
compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}    
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
compile project(':rangebar')
compile project(':expandablerecyclerview')
compile project(':materialsearchview')
// Play Services
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:11.4.2'
// Firebase
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev66-1.22.0'
// Just GSON
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
// Don't remember what is it about

// View binder
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
// Social SDK's
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.20.0'
// Glide libs
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.1'
// SquareUp libs
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.7.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.7.0'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
compile 'com.github.florent37:dagger-auto-inject:1.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.florent37:dagger-auto-inject-compiler:1.0.0'
compile('com.hwangjr.rxbus:rxbus:1.0.5') {
    exclude group: 'com.jakewharton.timber', module: 'timber'
}
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
// ?
compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
// ?
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.1.0'
compile 'com.yqritc:recyclerview-flexibledivider:1.4.0'
compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.7'
compile 'com.r0adkll:slidableactivity:2.0.5'
compile 'com.github.asyl.animation:arcanimator:1.0.0'
compile 'com.pacioianu.david:ink-page-indicator:1.2.0'
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.6'
// Circular adapter for picker
compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:adapter-kit:0.5.3'
// RX libs
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.0'
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.3.0'
compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.6.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
//CALENDAR
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'
compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.3.2'
compile 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.1.0'
compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.13@aar'
compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3'
compile 'net.time4j:time4j-android:3.29-2017a'
// TODO CHECK
compile 'com.github.michael-rapp:android-material-dialog:4.0.1'
compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:1.0.0'
// TODO CHECK
compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.0.2'
compile 'com.github.markomilos:paginate:0.5.1'
compile 'com.github.jimcoven:jcropimageview:0.22'
compile 'ru.egslava:MaskedEditText:1.0.5'
compile 'com.github.delight-im:Android-SimpleLocation:v1.0.1'
```

Comment: try to `gradlew dependencies` inside terminal.

Comment: Add output for `gradlew app:dependencies --configuration releaseCompileClasspath`

Comment: see [Another stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46995816/2877004)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add to build.gradle located in app module

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem please? and when I add this then error about can't find the httpclient library.

Comment: It is not working for me. I am getting Error:Error: json defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging the library using something like jarjar. [DuplicatePlatformClasses].

Answer (score 5):

In my case I use this dependency:

```
compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'
```

The json is wrong. I changed

```
implementation('com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0',{
    exclude group:'org.json',module: 'json'
})
```

Comment: I had 'io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0' in build.gradle and your solution worked for me. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The same error i fixed by this piece of code...

```
android {
...

configurations {
    all {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'json'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
}

...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add to app/build.gradle

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this with a clean/rebuild. Also be sure to have annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0' in your gradle for Glide.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
compile 'com.github.recruit-lifestyle:FloatingView:2.2'
compile 'com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.0.5'
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
compile 'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:26.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.2'

annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the first issue (commons-logging) was solved excluding it from opencsv import:

```
implementation('com.opencsv:opencsv:4.5') {
    exclude group: 'commons-logging'
}
```