# commons-logging defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android after Android Studio Update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0, android-gradle-3.0

I have updated Android Studio to version 3 and now seems unable to compile my project previously compiled without errors.

The error message is the follow

> Error:Error: commons-logging defines classes that conflict with
>   classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer
>   versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem
>   (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead),
>   or repackaging the library using something like jarjar.
>   [DuplicatePlatformClasses]

The dependencies are

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.23.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
}
```

and error seems caused by

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.23.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
```

I already use `exclude module: 'httpclient'`
So why It doesn't compile?
Is this a bug of Android Studio 3 and\or included `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0` plugin or I'm missing something? With the previous version no problem to compile exactly the same project.

Comment: "So why It doesn't compile?" -- your problem is with `commons-logging`, based on the error. Perhaps there are newer versions of those `com.google` dependencies that you should be using.

Comment: @CommonsWareI haven't find any newer library these versions are latest October 2017 releases

Comment: Do you have same jars in libs folder?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti absolutely not. I haven't any jars in libs folder. The libraries are only specified in dependencies section in build.gradle (otherwise also the previous Android studio would have refused to build). For this reason I cannot figure why after Android Studio update won't compile.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Add to `build.gradle` located in app module

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not able to get release apk if exclude httpclient

Comment: @RameshSambu Have you placed the above code in the inner build.gradle of the app module?

Comment: Yes I added like that

Comment: you can find release apk at app/release

Comment: You have just saved me from a major release crisis. Thank you!

Comment: In which tag, do I need to put that?

Comment: @NerendraJi in configurations. If It's missing just copy paste the code that I have posted.

Comment: What if I'm using httpclient?  My code used to compile before upgrading to Android Studio 3.0.  I'm actually using httpclient in my code, and I don't want to switch to okhttp.

Comment: @user3562927 I am also facing and having the same issue as you are having. Did You got any solution for it, as in older version it was working. but after upggading Android Studio and Gradle it is not.

Comment: configurations {
        all {
            exclude module: 'httpclient'
            exclude module: 'commons-logging'
            exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
            exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
            exclude module: 'opengl-api'
            exclude module: 'xmlParserAPIs' exclude module: 'xpp3'

        }
    }
this works for me

Comment: Ok, but how libraries that use httpclient would work without it? LVL library of Google depends on org.apache.http

Comment: @ARLabs @user3562927 @Pravinsingh-Waghela You need to provide some different `httpclient` library/wrapper. You could try [this one](https://github.com/smarek/httpclient-android) - I was in the same situation yesterday and this library is the only solution that worked for me. You will only have to change all `org.apache.http` imports in your code to `cz.msebera.android.httpclient`.

Answer (score 55):

If the problem is with commons-logging then it must be excluded too.
Add the following code in app/build.gradle

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    }
}
```

Comment: this will exclude `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` what if our code is already using this library?

Comment: then you need to find that specific library which is causing this duplicate httpclient import and need to remove the transitive httpclient dependency from that specific library.

Comment: in my case, `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` was causing the conflict since android is now itself providing this library. Luckily, I found a clone github repo of `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` with different name space which solved my problem.

Comment: here is the clone, just in case if anyone want to use `implementation group: 'cz.msebera.android', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.2'`

Comment: thanks @MuhammadSaqib your clone solution (. implementation group: 'cz.msebera.android', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.2'  ) saved my day

Answer (score 14):

Got the same issue. I have done below changes

```
 configurations {
    all{
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
}


packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'org/apache/http/version.properties'
    exclude 'org/apache/http/client/version.properties'
}
```

Comment: Where to put this code? In App or Project Level Gradle? @Raja Peela

Comment: @PratikSaluja App level inside android {}

Comment: Weird for me it worked outside of the android block.

Comment: @Raja Peela, in my experience this solution can remove the error message of this question, but then the Google Drive API is influenced and failed. Do you have any idea about that?

Answer (score 9):

You should replace "compile" with "implementation" as it's deprecated in the latest gradle and exlude "org.apache.httpcomponents" from Google api client libraries:

```
implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
implementation('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
```

this solution was found here:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/v1/quickstart/android

Comment: compile: compile library for each which contain current module. 
implementation: compile library for current module, that's mean implemented library not visible for "parent" modules

Comment: but compile is deprecated in the new Android Studio so you'll get a warning to replace it with "implementation" or " api' & that depends on your need

Answer (score 8):

Run in terminal, inside project folder:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies > dependencies.txt
```

Then check dependencies.txt to find who is using conflictive dependencies and act accordingly (check for updates, get rid of it, or use exclude as suggested by @Silverstorm)

Comment: *Note*: `app:dependencies` - here `app` is the name of your app module, for example `myAwesomeApp`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to continue with `async-http` then add below following code only in `app/build.gradle`

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3' is deprecated after SDKversion 23 so

replace this:

```
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
```

with

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3'
```

Answer (score 1):

I received these two errors today.

```
1. commons-logging defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging the library using something like jarjar.

2. httpclient defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging the library using something like jarjar.
```

After struggling for sometime, I figured that I was using a Firebase library which was causing these errors.

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.2.0')
```

So, I updated it:

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.2.1')
```

And `Invalidated Caches and Restarted` the project and it worked like a charm.

> Earlier BOM version of Firebase was also working fine.
>
> ```
> implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.1.0')
> ```
>
> **Please don't update Firebase BOM version: 29.2.0**

Answer (score 0):

I removed commons-logging as suggested above, *of course* it crashed on some phone with `Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory;`. How can Android claim the commons-logging is conflicting with Android API when the Android API doesn't contain any of those classes?!? There is no org.apache.commons.logging at https://developer.android.com/reference/packages :facepalm:

I've added back `implementation 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.0.4'` to the build.gradle - Android Studio underlines it with red but gradle compiles happily. :facepalm:

Android :triple_facepalm:

Comment: Those classes are not exposed as public API, though they are used as part of implementation. To see an example of such conflict, check [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9126567).

Answer (score 0):

if you are facing this issue because of `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime` dependency, then use this in your **app level build.gradle file:**

```
implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.12') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
}
implementation "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.13"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to join multiple solutions from here. This is what worked for me:

```
    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
        configureEach {
            exclude module: 'httpclient'
            exclude module: 'commons-logging'
            exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
            exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this then sync your gradle

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
    all*.exclude module: 'httpclient'
    all*.exclude module: 'commons-logging'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in my case android studio couldn't recognize "httpclient"
so i couldn't use @Silverstorm answer.

instead found another answer:
[Error: json defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47018437/error-json-defines-classes-that-conflict-with-classes-now-provided-by-android/47410498)

which implies to add below could in app build.gradle:

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
}
```