# Issue with gradle in android studio while building a signed APK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to build a signed APK for my project using android studio. The error I'm getting:

```
Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.

To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:
...
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
...
```

In the `reports/lint-results-release-fatal.html` I have the following error:

[image]

[From previous topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46989310/commons-logging-defines-classes-that-conflict-with-classes-now-provided-by-andro), I tried to add the following code in the gradle:

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    }
}
```

Which helped to solve the problem but then I get another problem in runtime (when running the app):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory;
```

On the line:

```
TimeZoneRegistry registry = TimeZoneRegistryFactory.getInstance().createRegistry();
```

The grandle file looks as following:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.2.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.1'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'

    implementation 'com.github.pchmn:MaterialChipsInput:1.0.8'
    implementation 'com.github.Plumillon:ChipView:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.4.0'

    implementation 'org.mnode.ical4j:ical4j:1.0.5'
    implementation 'backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:3.1'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
    implementation 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
    implementation 'com.linkedin.android.tachyon:tachyon:1.0.2'
}
```

What could be the issue? I really prefer to fix the issue, instead of ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solve it with this youtube helper.

[reference video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02nnu_1a0Qo)

1. Go to buil.gradle(Module: app)
2. write below code above "compieSdkVersion"

   lintOptions{

   checkReleaseBuilds false

   }
3. Build again

Comment: But that's is just ignoring the problem no?