# Error [duplicateplatformclasses] while building app in release mode

Tags: java, android

After updating Android Studio and updated GDAA to Google Drive REST API as GDAA is deprecated, but now I can not build my app in release mode which had no issues before. Here is the complete error message:

> org.gradle.api.GradleException: Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target. To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:
>   ...
>   android {
>       lintOptions {
>           checkReleaseBuilds false
>           // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
>           // but continue the build even when errors are found:
>           abortOnError false
>       }
>   }

And in the **lint-results-release-fatal.xml** file I get these messages:

> 'commons-logging' defines classes that conflict with classes now
>   provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or
>   alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example,
>   for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or
>   repackaging the library using something like jarjar.
>
> 'httpclient' defines classes that conflict with classes now provided
>   by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative
>   libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for
>   httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging
>   the library using something like jarjar.

Here is my gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.26.0'
    implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.26.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev136-1.25.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
}
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47147606/commons-validator-and-error-commons-logging-defines-classes-that-conflict-with) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46989310/commons-logging-defines-classes-that-conflict-with-classes-now-provided-by-andro) but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all other solutions with no luck, I suddenly discovered that this version of Android Studio 3.3.2 does not detect libraries which are out of date and found that the library causing the problem was this:

```
implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.26.0'
```

As this is the suspected library from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54355038/lint-error-httpclient-defines-classes-that-conflict-with-classes-now-provided).

I simply updated this library to the latest version which is this at the moment:

```
implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.28.0'
```

And the problem was solved.

I post this question and give answer just because I could not find the right answer and for those struggling with the same problem could be the right solution.